# Home Postgress Server Configuration

Tags: windows, postgresql, sql

I have postgresql server installed on my main computer (my desktop). I am working on a hobby project via node.js and sometimes would like to work from my laptop when i can not be at my desktop.

How would I go about setting up my laptop in order to connect to my postgresql db that is hosted locally on my desktop?

I do not need access outside of my home network just inside.

pg_hba settings used:

## IPv4 local connections:

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

## IPv6 local connections:

host    all             all             ::0/0                   md5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. laptop is on same subnet as desktop
2. some sort of Postgres driver/client on laptop (psql or PGAdmin or Node driver)
3. desktop firewall allowing TCP 5432 from laptop
4. PostgreSQL server is listening on your desktop network interface, not loopback. Set `listen_addresses='*'` in `postgres.conf`
5. TCP authentication setup in `pg_hba.conf`, something like:

   ```
   host  all  all   samenet  md5
   ```